# Best way to identify HtmlControl for Coded UI scripts

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am manually writing some scripts to test a web application with Coded UI. What is the best way to know which HtmlControl tag I should be using for the elements I want to manipulate? For example, how can I easily tell if I should be using HtmlDiv or HtmlSpan, etc? I know that the tag gives a hint, but is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the object recorder that comes with [CUITe](https://cuite.codeplex.com/). That records the object properties for you as well for easy copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

Use browser development mode (like firebug in Firefox) to identify what is what.

You can also use inspect.exe application ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to help with other windows that are not a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try to extract object information with ExecuteScript method of BrowserWindow

```
object control = BrowserWindow.ExecuteScript("return $('#yourControlId');");
```

if your control is of Type ***HtmlCustom*** then on hover on return type it will display **CustomType[Custom]** or **CustomType[Span]** for **HtmlSpan** then you can easily cast it to the appropriate control.

If you have only HtmlDiv and HtmlSpan control then you can use generic method as well perform any action on them

```
           protected void PerformAction(object control)
           { 
                object htmlControl = ((List<object>)control)[0];
                HtmlDiv htmldiv = htmlControl  as HtmlDiv;
                HtmlSpan htmlspan = null;

                if (htmldiv == null)
                {
                    htmlspan = htmlControl  as HtmlSpan ;

                    if (htmlspan != null){
                       // Write your action  
                    }
                }

                if (htmldiv == null && htmlspan == null) return;
                // Do your code
            }
```

On hover it you can get your control info as in attached screenshot.

[image]